# Transparent listview c#

Tags: c#, listview, .net-4.0

I want to change **listview backcolor** to **transparent**
I searched but can't find it
please anyone can help me?

Sorry for my English.

Comment: Google "c# lvs_ex_transparentbkgnd" for hits.  Best to target 4.5, this can't work on XP.

Comment: I know but my operating system is windows xp

Answer (score 0):

`<ListView Background="Transparent">`

Comment: It maybe work in wpf programs only It will not work in WinForms

Answer (score 0):

Works in win form if you use superclass ListView adding `SetStyle(System.Windows.Forms.ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, true);` to its initialization before setting the color to transparency